# How to pass aws credential and config to aws sdk in nodejs programmatically?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services

I am building an environment which let users to run their nodejs code. It is pretty much like what `Code Pen` or `runit` does. If users need to run aws sdk code in the environment, I don't know how to handle their credentials and configs. I know aws nodejs sdk has a method `config()` which I can pass all configuration in. But usually developers aws credentials and config are saved in `~/.aws/credential` and `~/.aws/config` files. If I ask users to upload these files into the environment, how can I convert them into a parameter can be read by aws sdk? Is there a easy way to do or I have to manually parse these files?

Comment: Can you include the code itself

Comment: None of this sounds like a great idea to me from a security perspective. You should try hard to avoid asking for credentials like this.

Comment: Maybe this can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69921864/6491200

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

// config.json
{"accessKeyId": <YOUR_ACCESS_KEY_ID>, "secretAccessKey": <YOUR_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY>, "region": "us-east-1" }


AWS.config.loadFromPath('./config.json');
```

You can also do it like this:

```
var AWS = require("aws-sdk");

AWS.config.update({
  region: "us-west-2",
  "accessKeyId": <YOUR_ACCESS_KEY_ID>, 
  "secretAccessKey": <YOUR_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY>
});
```

Comment: A solution using env vars: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69921864/6491200

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example of hard-coding credentials for the Simple Email Service (SES) in AWS SDK **v3**:

```js
let { SES } = require("@aws-sdk/client-ses");

const ses = new SES({
  apiVersion: "2010-12-01",
  region: "us-west-1",
  credentials: {
    accessKeyId: ".....", 
    secretAccessKey: ".....",
  },
});
```

I'm guessing it's basically the same for other AWS constructors - i.e. just add that `credentials` property with the access keys in it.

(Note that hard-coding your credentials like this convenient, but can be a bad idea for professional/production applications where security is important. See the links [at the bottom of this page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/setting-credentials-node.html) for several other approaches that are more secure.)

Answer (score 0):

You definitely DON'T want to save your AWS credentials in the file. A better way to do it would be to save the values in an environment variable in the environment your app is going to be running on. If you have the `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` environment variables set, the SDK will automatically load them, and you don't have to worry about it in your code, as described here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/loading-node-credentials-environment.html Depending on which services you are using, these values might already be set. If not, it should be pretty easy to create a user or role that has permissions for whatever operations you are using the SDK for.