# Firebase Webhooks / User Events into AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, firebase, google-cloud-functions, webhooks

I am looking to leverage Firebase's authentication for my app's users; however I have a graphql api deployed in AWS which has a dynamodb table which holds my User records.

I initially didn't see this as a problem cause my app + firebase handles the signup / login on the client side - and simply sends an JWT token to the graphql api which I have working - but I still want to be able to respond to user events.

My issue is that I don't see a good way to ingest user events such that I can make updates to my User database.

Seems like there aren't outgoing webhooks from firebase - but there are cloud functions to respond to events like `onCreate` or `onDelete` for users.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/extend-with-functions

Is there a way to setup webhooks so that I can respond to those events outside the google / firebase world?  Would love to avoid the extra steps involved in a solution like this:

```
<User Created> -> Trigger Google Cloud Function -> send HTTP request to webhook -> Create user record in my Database

<User Deleted> -> Trigger Google Cloud Function -> send HTTP request to webhook -> Delete user record in my Database
```

Any guidance on how to best handle this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hi @9er, to clarify, you want to be able to respond to Firebasee Auth events on create/deleetee users without using Cloud Functions triggeer right?

Comment: I don't think there is anything simpler than what you have written as a example solution.

Comment: @MarcAnthonyB yes - that's correct - I've used Auth0 in the past and utilized their "partner event bus" to respond to user events within AWS.  I could create functions to pass events into AWS via custom webhooks via Cloud Functions - but ideally would like to avoid the extra step if there is a better way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

The Firebase Function is just NodeJS code that can include AWS credentials.
You can use the client library of your database within your function to perform create/read/update/delete whenever a user is created. A webhook can be skipped for this case.

The flow should be like this:

```
<User Created> -> Trigger Google Cloud Function -> Create user record in my Database
<User Deleted> -> Trigger Google Cloud Function -> Delete user record in my Database
```

You can include your AWS credential when you deploy your code in Firebase Functions, here's a related **[thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59345184/how-to-set-aws-s3-credentials-in-a-google-firebase-cloud-function)** as a reference.

After setting AWS in Google Firebase Cloud Function, you should be able to use it to directly create/read/update/delete users in your AWS DynamoDB without needing to go through a webhook.

You may refer to the Amazon DynamoDB [Create, Read, Update, and Delete an Item](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GettingStarted.NodeJs.03.html) for more information.